# How to connect my meteor application to an external MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have `Node.JS` server hosted in heroku and I want to use the same Mongo database in my `Meteor` application.

Here is my Mongo database in my `Node.js` server:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var messageSchema   = new Schema({
    requestNumber: String,
    requestedDateTime: String,
    reasons: String,
    state: String,
    hospital: String,
    phone: String,
    status: {type: String, default: 'Pending'},
    latestUpdate: Date,
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Requests', messageSchema);
```

And here is my collection in `Meteor`:

```
Requests = new Mongo.Collection("requests");

Requests.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    requestNumber: {type: String},
    requestedDateTime: {type: String},
    reasons: {type: String},
    state: {type: String},
    hospital: {type: String},
    phone: {type: String},
    status: {type: String, defaultValue: 'Pending'},
    latestUpdate: {type: Date},
    createdAt: {type: Date, defaultValue: Date.now}
}));

Requests.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc){
    return true;
  },
  update: function(userId, doc, fields, modifier){
    return true;
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc){
    return true;
  }
});
```

Here is how I am connecting to my `Node.JS` database inside `Meteor` app:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    process.env.MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://...';
});
```

When I try `db.requests.find().pretty()` in `meteor mongo/mongo shell`, nothing is printed to the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a wrong way to connect to external DB. You're specifying `MONGO_URL` *after* your app has started and at this point it already has started internal mongo server.

You should specify `MONGO_URL` while running your meteor app from console:

```
MONGO_URL="mongodb://..." meteor
```

You can use a tiny `sh` script to do that:

```
#!/bin/sh
MONGO_URL="mongodb://..." meteor -s <path_to_settings_file> ... <other_parameters>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it and it seems to be working because I can't use "meteor mongo" command since it connects to local mongo only. but how can I make sure that it is connected? I tried "console.log(Requests.find({}))" but nothing was returned. Sorry for taking of your time.

Comment: You can use `meteor shell` and run commands there, like `Requests.find().fetch()`

Comment: I actually can see it in "meteor shell" but inside the code, Requests.find({}) returns nothing, do you know why?